# Evitar auto relleno Microsoft edge

Tags: c#, asp, autocompletar

tengo una agina en asp y en un Textbox tengo el auto completar como false, aun así solo en edge me sigue auto rellenando ¿alguna idea de que puedo hacer?

Comment: Tal vez tengas que inhabilitar desde Edge el auto completar, te dejo el siguiente enlace para ver si es de utilidad [inhabilitar autocomplete](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000604.htm#edge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendaria que uses `off` en lugar de `false`

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off"/>
```

para deshabilitar el autocomplete

Comment: Gracias, ya intente ambas opciones y no funciona,  entraran a la página otras personas en sus propias maquinas y no puedo desactivar el autocompletado en cada una.

Comment: parece ser un problema conocido que viene dese IE11 https://blog.gerv.net/2013/10/ie-11-ignoring-autocompleteoff/